# Getting Python using os.walk() to generate a textfile containing the directory structure for a given path

Tags: python, ios

```
import os

def record_directory_structure(directory_path: str, file_name: str):
    with open(file_name, "w") as file:
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory_path):
            level = root.replace(directory_path, '').count(os.sep)
            indent = ' ' * 4 * (level)
            file.write('{}{}/\n'.format(indent, os.path.basename(root)))
            subindent = ' ' * 4 * (level + 1)
            for f in files:
                file.write('{}{}\n'.format(subindent, f))

record_directory_structure("path", "DirectoryStructure.txt")
```

performs satisfactorily until it bombs out when encountering a filename containing a Cyrillic or Greek character. Following the advice that this is due to such characters being non-ASCII and `os.walk()` expecting Unicode characters I was hopeful the following to be a fix:

```
def record_directory_structure(directory_path: str, file_name: str):
    with open(file_name, "w") as file:
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory_path):
            level = root.replace(directory_path, '').count(os.sep)
            indent = ' ' * 4 * (level)
            file.write('{}{}/\n'.format(indent, os.path.basename(root)))
            subindent = ' ' * 4 * (level + 1)
            for f in files:
                # Encode the Unicode string to bytes using UTF-8
                encoded_f = f.encode('utf-8')
                # Decode the bytes back to a Unicode string
                decoded_f = encoded_f.decode('utf-8')
                # Do something with the decoded name
                file.write('{}{}\n'.format(subindent, decoded_f))
```

It wasn't. Anyone?

Comment: What is this `"it bombs out"` that you speak of? Is there an error message that you could include in your question?

Comment: apologies for being vague, the message is ```, line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u03a3' in position 4: character maps to <undefined>
```

Comment: It helps to include details like this in the question, also the full traceback so it's possible to see which line of the code you've posted is failing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A shot in the dark without more information, but I'm guessing that your error looks like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\BoppreH\tmp\dirs.py", line 16, in <module>
    record_directory_structure("path", "DirectoryStructure.txt")
  File "C:\Users\BoppreH\tmp\dirs.py", line 14, in record_directory_structure
    file.write('{}{}\n'.format(subindent, f))
  File "C:\Python312\Lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 4-11: character maps to <undefined>
```

The issue is at this line:

```
    with open(file_name, "w") as file:
```

When you open a text file, [Python needs to know the *encoding* for that file](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html). The encoding is a way to map logical characters like "letter 'a' with acute accent" into actual bytes that you can write to a file. Python strings are UTF-8, which is extremely versatile, but has many characters that are simply untranslatable to other encodings.

The default encoding used by `open` depends on the environment, including operating system, language, and what terminal you're using. You can check what's your default encoding with this snippet:

```
import locale
print(locale.getpreferredencoding())
# Prints "cp1252" on my Windows machine, *not* UTF-8.
```

So what happens is that Python saw a file with Cyrillic/Greek characters, and created strings from it just fine (UTF-8). But when writing to the text file, the default encoding has no way to represent those characters. Hence the error.

The solution is to simply specify the file encoding to be UTF-8 too:

```
def record_directory_structure(directory_path: str, file_name: str):
    #       Add this:         vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
    with open(file_name, "w", encoding='utf-8') as file:
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory_path):
            level = root.replace(directory_path, '').count(os.sep)
            indent = ' ' * 4 * (level)
            file.write('{}{}/\n'.format(indent, os.path.basename(root)))
            subindent = ' ' * 4 * (level + 1)
            for f in files:
                file.write('{}{}\n'.format(subindent, f))
```

Now you're free to write UTF-8 strings to the file, because Python doesn't need to translate the encoding.

Comment: Lucid explanation. Problem solved with the addition of ```, encoding='utf-8')``` to the ```open``` statement. Thanks.

Comment: Surely `utf-8` is an *encoding*. Python strings are [unicode](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html), so it sounds like `encoding='utf-8'` is just a very suitable encoding when writing to files. (I don't know whether python does this or whether the undelying os can handle it)

Comment: @quamrana Good point. I didn't want to complicate things further with a new concept (Unicode vs UTF-8), but you're right that Python strings might not be actually UTF-8 internally, just "compatible".